# rails, provide visual feedback on a password, yet keeping it secure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I've a password stored in a database. 
The user should be able to set a new one. 
I've also used attr_encrypted gem to store it as encrypted text (symmetric because i need it back to connect to other services and not just to login) but this is another story. 
When I show the form, **the default behavior of ruby helpers is to not send back the password to the browser** for obvious security reasons. 
Here is the code:

```
<%= f.input :app_password, :as => :password %>
```

this behavior might be ok, nevertheless some issues arise from it.

- if the user saves the form with null password, the password will be erased. I should test and avoid null-password savings but in some application null password is acceptable and doing so i would prevent this possibility.
- it doesn't provide a visual feedback to the user on the fact that he or she has compiled the password field.
- it doesn't play very well with validations

What are my options here in order to obtain the most standard possible behavior (that is, no 'change password' checkboxes)?

Comment: First, I'd create a separate form for changing the password and only password (not sure if that's the case for you, or you are letting the user change it along with other fields). Second, obviously, have both password and password_confirmation there and check that they match. Third, make the user enter the existing password along with the new one, so that the user can't just erase it by clicking 'OK' w/o any thought. Plus, if you want, detect an empty new password, and ask 'Are you sure?'

Answer (score 0):

Please, in forms include password fields this way:

```
<%= f.password_field :app_password %>
```

The standard use and set of password is:

Add to your user model a call to `has_secure_password`

Add field to users for store an encripted password, migration: `add_column :users, :auth_token, :string`

Before create generate a token:

```
begin
  self.auth_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
end while User.exists?(auth_token: self.auth_token)
```

Authenticate your users with `@user.authenticate(params[:password])`

Update password at another form with 3 fields, old_password, password, and password_confirmation.